# Define a certain layout in flutter where the card with a specific id remains at first postition and is double the size of rest of the cards?

Tags: android, flutter, gridview

I am having a list of users and i want to show a particular user at the first position with double the size and the rest as small cards later.

I tried using the grid view but it wasn't as expected.

Comment: what kind of layout you want , can you provide a image of what you are trying to achieve